# Correct user session/cookie handling with external site connection in wordpress

Tags: cookies, server, session

I have a wordpress + woocommerce site where the user can configure a product and create a custom one. The software that handle this configuration is on another server. So i need to send some data in POST and then, after the procedure on the external site is completed, retrieve the data and save the product as a woocommerce product. Actually i send the id of the user to the external site and retrieve it in post (the external site pass back the value that i've sent without changes).

This is the scenario:
1 - page1.php on the wordpress site --> form that send post data to external url. The user is already logged on woocommerce.
The form is like this:

```
<form action="external site url.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="CC" value="userID"> // this value is the wordpress user ID and is passed on external site
... other form fields
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2 - The user is redirected to external site and do some stuff, after that the external site send post data and redirect on wordpress site

3 - page2.php on the wordpress site --> receive post data.
The code that read the post data is like this:

```
if($_POST && $_POST['DO'] == 'save') {
  $userID = $_POST['CC'];
  wp_set_current_user($userID); 
  //take the other post parameters and do stuff...
}
```

In particular $POST['CC'] is the id of the user.
**The problem is that the user when is redirected on page2.php is not logged anymore on woocommerce.** So i've used wp_set_current_user since i have the id of the user in post.
I hope that now it's more clear.

Is it correct?

Comment: That's extremely unusual, are you wiping cookies or changing the domain when the user  comes back? There is no best practice answer for handling this situation because this situation should not happen in a best practice scenario. When you say session, does that mean you're trying to use PHP Sessiions? Or are you referring to the standard WordPress cookies?

Comment: Actually i don't use sessions. What i do is retrive the current user id with this code: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); $user_ID = $current_user->ID;` Then i pass the id via post to the external site and when i have the value back, i set the current user. Maybe is better to store the current user in a Session and retrieve it in the $_SESSION variable after the post data are received? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: you should not need to set the current user unless you've built a completely bespoke login form. The browser should be sending cookies for that request. imo your `wp_set_current_user` is the cause of your problem, and it shouldn't be present anyway. I'd also strongly advise against PHP sessions, for one they don't work on a lot of WP hosts. All PHP sessions will do is make your situation more complicated without fixing the problem

Comment: I am a little confused as to how that code is running though, who is making the request? The remote server? Or is the user being redirected by the remote server meaning it's the browser that makes the request? It's not clear, and it isn't clear what type of request or where it's being handled

Comment: I've added some code and edited the question so i hope that now it's more clear